# Want to stop ping from script

Tags: android, shell, adb, ping

Have a charming day ahead for you.

I was trying to implement adb ping in scripts and I want to have adb ping statistics at any point of time. Like I want to know how many pings were sent and how many are received at any point of time.

And eventually, I want to stop ping. I know we have to press <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> for stopping ping, but how can we do that from adb shell command? I could not find any adb shell function for stopping ping.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of doing it. I would ping it x-times, in this case 10 times:

```
ping -c 10 www.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
ping <destination> &
PID=$!
```

and at any given time later

```
kill $PID
```